# How to start mining and ipc port open

Tags: go-ethereum

I know how to start mining and open ipc port seperately. First I unlocked my account using `geth --datadir "ethereum/node1" --unlock ffc4136c8dd4ee4efb10ea954d65ad032ad86834 --password ethereum/password.txt`

Now I have unlocked my account and I have some ether that I have mined previously, now I want to put it in testing. So when I try to open ipc using `geth --datadir "ethereum/node1" --port 30301 --networkid 1234 --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*"` it always shows `datadir already used by another process`.

I want to open this port with unlocked account so I can using it. I don't want to use console commands because my server will time out after some time and it will close the console automatically.  How can I achieve this? Can some one help me in this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself an answer. Using `geth attach ipc:ethereum/node1/geth.ipc console 2>console.log` this command we can connect to that node and perform any operation using console command and we finally exit.

Answer (score -2):

To start mining, you need to first set up a mining rig. This involves purchasing the necessary hardware components, such as a graphics card, processor, and motherboard. You will also need to install a mining software program and join a mining pool. Once all of this is set up, you can begin mining.

To open an IPC port, you will need to use a program such as a port forwarding software. This will allow you to open a port on your computer and allow it to communicate with other computers on the network. You will need to specify the port number, protocol, and IP address you want to use. Once the port is open, you can start mining.

Comment: Downvoted this most likely AI generated answer